# Ghostscript Error with pst-vectorian

Tags: ghostscript

When trying to use pst-vectorian, I'm getting an error: GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newcommand{\ornamentalBreak}{%
    \begin{center}
        \psvectorian[width=2in]{83} 
    \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
    asdf asdfjkajs;df
    
    \ornamentalBreak
    
    asdfsdfaslfd;

\end{document}
```

My pst-vectorian package is v. 41 (rev 60488). I'm using TexLive on Windows and compiling with Xelatex. I noticed that Ghostscript is currently at 9.55, but I can't figure out how to get the version in Texlive to update to that.

ADD: tlgs.win32 now updated to  rev 60648 so now I'm getting version 9.55 in Latex but still the same error.

Comment: Have yuo tried using `lualatex` instead? Xelatex fails for me too on linux, but `lualatex` compiles

Comment: It does work for me in `lualatex`, thanks. I feel like there was a reason I was using Xelatex for something that I can't remember, though. I'll have to see how it affects the rest of my files.

Comment: I think if starting out, jump straight to lualatex, it is easier to work with in certain ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from Herbert Voss, adding `-output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E"` to my compilation `xelatex` command was a functional workaround.