Does anyone have an MWE for "swissqrcode"?
I have been using \qrcode to create QR codes, but I ran into an issue doing the "official" Swiss banking QR codes. As soon as there is an umlaut, the code is declared invalid - somehow UTF-8 doesn't translate into that QR code.
Having the choice of either replacing all umlauts (tedious) or using another QR-generator I saw that pst-barcode has a dedicated option "swissqrcode".
However, I do not get a result - so I guess I must make a rookie mistake here. Below is my MnonWE - and I can add that leaving out the ^^J didn't help either.
Can anyone help me make this into an MWE so I have a starting point?
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
\psbarcode{SPC^^J
0200^^J
1^^J
CH5800791123000889012^^J
S^^J
Robert Schneider AG^^J
Rue du Lac^^J
1268^^J
2501^^J
Biel^^J
CH^^J
^^J
^^J
^^J
^^J
^^J
^^J
^^J
199.95^^J
CHF^^J
S^^J
Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder^^J
Grosse Marktgasse^^J
28^^J
9400^^J
Rorschach^^J
CH^^J
SCOR^^J
RF18539007547034^^J
^^J
EPD
}{width=10.0 height=10.0}{swissqrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

And here's the log, as requested:
*****
*****     XLX-Barcode output: 
*****     cd "/home/------------"
*****     xelatex -output-driver=xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode ps-tricks-test.tex
*****
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ps-tricks-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (./pst-barcode.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)))
`PSTricks' v3.13  <2022/01/09> (tvz,hv)
--- We are running latex or xelatex ---
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-color.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arrows.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dots.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for LaTeX+dvipdfmx
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-barcode/pst-barcode.tex
`PST-barcode' v0.19, 2022/08/21 (tb,hv)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./ps-tricks-test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1]
(./ps-tricks-test.aux)Error: /undefinedresource in findresource
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   (SPC\n 0200\n 1\n CH5800791123000889012\n S\n Robert Schneider AG\n Rue du Lac\n 1268\n 2501\n Biel\n CH\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n 199.95\n CHF\n S\n Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder\n Grosse Marktgasse\n 28\n 9400\n Rorschach\n CH\n ...)   ()   swissqrcode   uk.co.terryburton.bwipp   swissqrcode
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   findresource   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   findresource   findresource   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   findresource   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1916   5   4   %oparray_pop   findresource   %errorexec_pop   findresource   findresource
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:796/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:121/200(L)--   --dict:127/200(L)--   --dict:16/16(ro)(G)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 894
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 )
Output written on ps-tricks-test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on ps-tricks-test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on ps-tricks-test.log.


There is one mistake in your code: the swissqrcode has fixed size (46mmx46mm), so you should remove the width/height options from \psbarcode. Other than that, I can confirm that the MWE as you provided build fine. Can you post your log? (Quick rookie question: you are compiling using latex ... followed by dvips or dvipdf right? In particular you are not trying to build your MWE using pdflatex, right?)

Thank you! I removed the width/height options, this changed nothing (not saying that you implied it would.
I think I am compiling correctly, because in my code I had added
\psbarcode{0123456}{height=.5}{code39}
which doesn't display when using pdflatex but does display in my setting.
However, the swissqrcode doesn't.
I'll edit my question to post the log...

well the log shows an ghostscript  error. Try with latex+dvips+ps2pdf instead.

where is the umlaut in this example?

Maybe it's the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617119/ghostscript-error-with-pst-vectorian? That post provides two solutions, either xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" or lualatex.

Can you try updating your system? Your pstricks.sty is older than the current release, and your Ghostscript (9.55) is from 2021. Sometimes this helps.
